# User Profile Service fails after every one hour

Tags: sharepoint-server

1) UPSA and Proxy both are in started phase

2) It is a standalone SP server with SQL being on same server, no Farm

3) I don't think I understand you completely here

Note: This is PROD server, so it is not the case where USPA is completely down, users have complained that user profile fails intermittently.

**(Example 1:00 PM) Event 1:**

> Failure trying to synch web application X1 (guid), ContentDB X2 
>   Exception message was
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 582f0790-f2b1-4be2-a92e-e861b91782ac
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType
>   logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState, SyncType
>   syncType, WSSSyncUsageEntry usage, String[]
>   excludedAccountsRegexStrings)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

**(Example 1:00 PM) Event 2:**

> Failure trying to synch web application Y1, ContentDB Y2  Exception
>   message was
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 582f0790-f2b1-4be2-a92e-e861b91782ac
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType
>   logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState, SyncType
>   syncType, WSSSyncUsageEntry usage, String[]
>   excludedAccountsRegexStrings)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

**(Example 2:00 PM) Event 3:**

> Failure trying to synch web application X1 (guid), ContentDB X2 
>   Exception message was
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 582f0790-f2b1-4be2-a92e-e861b91782ac
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType
>   logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState, SyncType
>   syncType, WSSSyncUsageEntry usage, String[]
>   excludedAccountsRegexStrings)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

**(Example 2:00 PM) Event 4:**

> Failure trying to synch web application Y1, ContentDB Y2  Exception
>   message was
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException:
>   UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging ::
>   UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache
>   does not have 582f0790-f2b1-4be2-a92e-e861b91782ac
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_ApplicationProperties()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_PerfmonInstanceHandle()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer..ctor(ELogType
>   logType, SPContentDatabase cdb, SPJobState jobState, SyncType
>   syncType, WSSSyncUsageEntry usage, String[]
>   excludedAccountsRegexStrings)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager and select Authentication , select Anonymous authentication , then Edit ,select Specific User and provide “IUSR” without any password .

You need also pay attention to the "Timer Service Recycle" job running during off peak hours, when a small amount of timer jobs are running .